# How to replace(fill) None entries on List of Options from another List using idiomatic Scala?

Tags: list, scala, idioms

I have a `List[Option[MyClass]]` with `None` in random positions and I need to 'fill' that list again, from a `List[MyClass]`, maintaining the order.

Here are sample lists and expected result:

```
val listA = List(Some(3),None,Some(5),None,None)
val listB = List(7,8,9)
val expectedList = List(Some(3), Some(7), Some(5), Some(8), Some(9))
```

So, how would be a idiomatic Scala to process that list?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def fillL[T](a:List[Option[T]], b:List[T]) = {
    val iterB = b.iterator
    a.map(_.orElse(Some(iterB.next)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The iterator solution is arguably idiomatic Scala, and is definitely concise and easy to understand, but it's not *functional*—any time you call `next` on an iterator you're firmly in the land of side effects.

A more functional approach would be to use a fold:

```
def fillGaps[A](gappy: List[Option[A]], filler: List[A]) =
  gappy.foldLeft((List.empty[Option[A]], filler)) {
    case ((current, fs), Some(item)) => (current :+ Some(item), fs)
    case ((current, f :: fs), None) => (current :+ Some(f), fs)
    case ((current, Nil), None) => (current :+ None, Nil)
  }._1
```

Here we move through the gappy list while maintaining two other lists: one for the items we've processed, and the other for the remaining filler elements.

This kind of solution isn't necessarily better than the other—Scala is designed to allow you to mix functional and imperative constructions in that way—but it does have potential advantages.

Comment: "any time you call next on an iterator you're firmly in the land of side effects." True, but in this case they're neatly encapuslated in the method, which stays referentially transparent.

Comment: @Paul: Right, I think the other solution is great, and it's the approach I'd choose to solve this problem in my own code. But it does involve side effects, and in some similar situations that might not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just write it in the straightforward way, matching on the heads of the lists and handling each case appropriately:

```
def fill[A](l1: List[Option[A]], l2: List[A]) = (l1, l2) match {
  case (Nil, _) => Nil
  case (_, Nil) => l1
  case (Some(x) :: xs, _) => Some(x) :: fill(xs, l2)
  case (None :: xs, y :: ys) => Some(y) :: fill(xs, ys)
}
```

Presumably once you run out of things to fill it with, you just leave the rest of the `None`s in there.